# How do I set up routes in my node + express app to pass an authenticate method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm following the auth0 backend set up tutorial, and I'm wondering how I can set up my routes in a separate file instead of in `app.js`.

In the tutorial, they create

```
var authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});
```

and then `app.use('/secured', authenticate);`

If I want to set up my routes in some routes folder `routes/index.js`, and I want to use this `authenticate()`, how can I set that up in my `app.js`?

I know I have to do something like `var routes = require('./routes/index.js');`, but how do I set up the `app.use( .. )` in this case so it uses `authenticate()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `routes` module in `./routes/index.js` like this:

```
// ./routes/index.js

module.exports = function (app) {
   app.get('/secured', getSecuredController);
};

function getSecuredController (req, res) {
   res.send('/secured OK');
}
```

And in your main `app.js` file:

```
// ./app.js

var initializeRoutes = require('./routes');
var authenticate = jwt({..});

app.use('/secured', authenticate);
initializeRoutes(app);
```

Comment: thanks this works but now i get a 404 when I hit `/v1/test`.  In my app.js, I have `app.use('/v1', authenticate);  initializeRoutes(app);` and in my routes.js I have `module.exports = function (app) { app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) { res.json({ message: 'hello' }); }); }`

Comment: You defined a route for `/test`, not for `/v1/test` ;-)

Comment: ah!  i see.  thank you!  i thought the routes defined after would be appended to the /v1

Answer (score 1):

You can return router from file routes/index.js:

```
// routes/index.js

const express = require('express');

module.exports = function(options) {
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
        // process route...
    });

    // define other routes...

    return router;
};
```

And the use it in server:

```
// server.js

const express = require('express');
const router = require('./routes/index.js');

const authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});

var app = express()

app.use('/secured', authenticate, router());
```

This will make your router configurable and reusable.

Comment: You're welcome. But actually my answer utilise more flexible and fluent interface and I recommend you to use it instead of Pierre's.